# How can stop the browser from trying to render the page until my javascript function is complete?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to be able to do this:

1: Wait till DOM is loaded
2: Tell the browser not to render the page yet
3: Perform manipulation of DOM with a javascript library of choice (I'm using dojo)
4: Tell the browser it can now render the page

Otherwise, the user sees the intial DOM state briefly before it's manipulated. It's gross.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just put a display hidden inline on the body and remove it when your script is done running.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using CSS to hide the content, showing it only after your function has executed? To the best of my knowledge there's no way to accomplish this with JavaScript alone.